# iOS Forward Firebase Dynamic Link to Web Code Base

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using firebase deeplinks to open my app with specific parameters. Therefore I am using the library https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-dynamic-links. In Android it's working fine. But in iOS, I do not receive the link in the web code base:

```
CapacitorFirebaseDynamicLinks.addListener(
  "deepLinkOpen",
  (data: { url: string }) => {
    console.log("Listener started);
  }
);
FirebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink().subscribe(
  async (res: IDynamicLink) => {
    console.log(res.deepLink);
    console.log(res.matchType);
  }
);
```

I followed the instructions of the plugin and firebase docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive) to set up the iOS part. Therefore, I implemented the continue and open url functions in AppDelegate.swift as described in firebase docs. Currently I am receiving the link in the continue function but I do not know how to forward it to the subscriber in the web code base.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
  let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
    print("link received");
    print(dynamiclink);
    print(error);
 }
return handled
```

}

There is no documentation about it, i also tried another deeplink plugin (https://github.com/ClipboardHealth/capacitor-firebase-dynamic-links).